# android viewpager in popupwindow

Tags: java, android, popup, android-viewpager

How can i place a swipeable `ViewPager` with three tabs inside a `PopupWindow`?
I'm totally curious about how to do that!
The popup window is opened in a custom `View`.

currently i have only the popupwindow, which works excellent:

```
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View popup_view = li.inflate(R.layout.popup_view, null);

final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
popup.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
popup.setHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

popup.setTouchable(true);
popup.setFocusable(true);

popup.setContentView(popup_view);
popup.showAtLocation(this, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
```

the popup_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- here i want to have the ViewPager with 3 tabs -->
```

so i have three more layouts (`tab_one.xml` `tab_two.xml` and `tab_three.xml`)
in which are for now only some test text.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this using fragments. Create a FragmentActivity which calls a DialogFragment to display the popup window. In it's view, you could define the ViewPager. Have a look at the following answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19552298/3030934